# adding getmtime() to db and getting TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm  trying to add all the file names and last modification time for files in a specific directory to a database in two different columns.  This is code I have:

```
def getlist (self):
    dbinput = self.txt_dest.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect ('dirdrill.db')   
    for files in os.listdir(dbinput):
        for modtime in os.path.getmtime(dbinput):
            with conn:
                cur = conn.cursor()
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_files(col_filename, col_modinfo) values (?,?)", files, modtime)
                conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    getinfo(self)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\GitHub\Tech-Academy-Projects\Python\dir_drill\dirdrill_func.py", line 69, in getlist
    for modtime in os.path.getmtime(dbinput):
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Do I need to convert the numbers that getmtime() returns into a human friendly format so that it is not a float?  If so, how?  Or should I be structuring the function a different way?

EDIT:
Thanks to some other help I found out that I just needed to change one line to modinfo = os.path.getmtime(dbinput).  Did that and it solved the float error.  However now it says that I am offering too many arguments, max 2 and I have 3, even thought I only see two.  Onto the next bug... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to the original question and the additional error I discovered.

In the original code I needed to change the following:

```
for modtime in os.path.getmtime(dbinput):
```

to:

```
modtime = os.path.getmtime(dbinput)
```

For the follow up error related to too many parameters, files and modinfo needed to be wrapped in parenthesis like so:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_files(col_filename, col_modinfo) values (?,?)", (files, modtime))
```

Hopes this helps anyone else experiencing the same error.